# Как убрать "Распродано" на товарах woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что на карточках товаров начались отображаться подписи "Распродано", хотя в вариациях он в наличии.

Заметил, что произошло это после того, как в YellowPencil удалил маленький блок, где содержалась надпись "Продано" (возможно совпадение)

Помогите решить проблему

Хочу дополнить, это происходит почему-то только в некоторых товарах

Comment: Помогаю: верни как было, а потом решай что хотел решить своим удалением в каком-то никому не известном "YellowPencil".

Comment: SeVlad, в том то и дело, деактивировал YellowPencil но эта проблема все равно не исчезла(

Comment: "Верни как было" - это НЕ отключить плагин, а отменить изменения (развернуть бекап в крайнем случае). А телепатов тут нет.